# How do you Separate the mobile app and WebView to have different user experiences?

Tags: flutter

I want to display a different experience on the mobile app and a different user experience on the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Using a state management like Cubit or Bloc, them you can create different screens for different platforms using the environment kIsWeb as a controller. The pages rules (states) will be shared by the management state.

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_cubit/latest/

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do this using `kIsWeb`.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return kIsWeb
        ? Scaffold(
            body: Text("Web"),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            body: Text("mobile"),
          );}
```

lets' say you need more info about `Platform`
like `Platform.isIOS` or more like

```
Platform.isAndroid
Platform.isFuchsia
Platform.isIOS
Platform.isLinux
Platform.isMacOS
Platform.isWindows
```